# Multiple riders on the same agenda

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

In Twilight Imperium 4th edition, a rider is a category of action card that says:

> After an agenda is revealed:
>
> You cannot vote on this agenda.  Predict aloud an outcome of this agenda.  If your prediction is correct, [GAIN SOME BENEFIT].

Examples of this are Politics Rider, Technology Rider, and Warfare Rider.

Can multiple players each play a rider on the same agenda?  Can one player play multiple riders on the same agenda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number of players can play any number of riders on a single agenda, provided each is a different rider.  If multiple players want to play the same rider, the player first in speaker-clockwise order has priority.

The relevant points from the rules reference:

> Multiple action cards with the same name cannot be played during a single timing window to affect the same units or game effect. Canceled cards do not count as being played.
>
> During the strategy and agenda phases, if there are multiple abilities
> that players wish to resolve at the same time, each player takes a
> turn resolving an ability starting with the speaker and proceeding
> clockwise.  This process continues until each player has resolved all
> the abilities that he wishes to resolve during that timing window.

There is nothing in the rules reference that prohibits a player from playing multiple riders specifically.  There is also nothing besides the above rule preventing several action cards being played in response to a single trigger.